# trying to print a leaderboard in python

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I am working on a college project and am trying to create a tournament system for academic and sports 'football, netball, maths, english...' The idea is to register 1-20 teams into a tournament and then input winners.
The program asks the user who won the game and then would +1 score to them.
Now i want to be able to print a leaderboard so that the user can see the 'standings' of the tournament. Can someone please help me with this?

'''

```
class Team:

    #setting this outside of a method allows us to get it or set it outside of the class in the main code like a "global" for the class.
    TeamName = ''

    def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamMembers):
        self.TeamNum = TeamNum
        self.TeamName = TeamName
        self.TeamMembers = TeamMembers

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team Number: {self.TeamNum} |-| Team Name: {self.TeamName} |-| Member Count: {self.TeamMembers} |-| Team Score: {self.TeamScore}'

class Game:
    
    def __init__(self, game_number, home_team, away_team, home_team_score, away_team_score):
        self.home_team = home_team
        self.away_team = away_team
        self.home_team_score = home_team_score
        self.away_team_score = away_team_score

    #a class method that returns the winner based on the scores
    def winner(self):
        if self.home_team_score > self.away_team_score:
            return self.home_team
        else:
            return self.away_team

#instead of lists, use dictionaries so you can refer to a game by its number, or a team by its name without having to jump through hoops. 
games={}
teams = {}

TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

print('')
for i in range(TeamCounter):
    NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
    MemberCount=input('How Many Members in Team? ')
    print('')
    #Add to the teams dictionary.
    teams[NameOfTeam] = Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount) 


#Lets collect info about the games in the tourny:
GameCounter=int(input("How many games are in the tournament?"))
for i in range(GameCounter):
    home_team = input("what was the name of the home team?")
    home_team_score = input("what was their score?")
    away_team = input("what was the name of the away team?")
    away_team_score = input("what was their score?")

    #create the game object
    this_game = Game(i, teams[home_team], teams[away_team], home_team_score, away_team_score)

    #Once we have this one game made we can see who won. Note that we call the method `winner()` for `this_game` object which returns a `Team` object for which we can get it's attribute `TeamName`: 
    print("It looks like "+this_game.winner().TeamName+" won the game!")

#this is where i want to add a leaderboard, to print the final standings of the tournament
```

'''

Comment: Quick Note: If the team name given for the home or away team is wrong, the entire program will crash with a [KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError). You might want to wrap that part with a try/except statement.

Comment: how would i go about doing this? i am quite new to python. @importhuh

Comment: https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/ should help. Inside `Try:` should be the `this_game =` line.

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep track for each team, how many times they won.

One way is to have a dictionary where key is of type `Team` (alternatively string - team name) and value is the number of won games. Lets save this into `team_won_games_count = {}`. At the end of second loop, when you print the winner, you could also increment amount of won games.

in first loop

```py
   team = Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount) 
   teams[NameOfTeam] = team
   # initialize new team in the new dictionary with 0 wins
   team_won_games_count[team] = 0
```

in second loop

```py
   winner = this_game.winner()
   print("It looks like "+winner.TeamName+" won the game!")
   # add 1 to won games
   team_won_games_count[winner] += 1
```

Now you can loop the new dictionary at the end to print the name and their scores, e.g.

```py
for team, won_games_count in team_won_games_count.items():
   print("team "+team.TeamName+" | "+won_games_count+" wins")
```

Another possibility is to add number of wins directly to the team

```py
class Team:
    def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamMembers):
        #...
        self.WonGamesCount = 0
```

in second loop

```py
   winner = this_game.winner()
   print("It looks like "+winner.TeamName+" won the game!")
   # add 1 to won games
   winner.WonGamesCount += 1
```

and print leaderboard looping over teams dictionary

You might also want to leaderboard to be sorted (team with most wins first). For that you could use `sorted` function with `key` argument:

(with first approach)

```py
# lambda accesses the value of dictionary as a key for sorting the key-value pairs
for team, won_games_count in sorted(team_won_games_count.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True):
   print("team "+team.TeamName+" | "+won_games_count+" wins")
```

Comment: How would i add the first solution into my code please?

Comment: I always included the part of original code to replace. Parts of loops (already indented code) are at end of loop's body (replaces usually 1 last line).

Comment: team = Team(i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount)
NameError: name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?

Comment: thats the `i` of the (first) loop. It should be in body. Anyway I did not run the code, so there might be some small mistakes. I tried to not modify original code so you could see what (general idea) could be added for what you want